# How to define getters and setters in javascript using object.defineproperty

Tags: javascript, html, defineproperty

I have been trying to write getters and setters using object.defineproperty,but could not .I have been trying this example but it throws an error as no firstName property defined.can someone please help me this

```js
function person(fName, lName) {


  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
    get:function() { return firstName; },
    set:function(newValue){firstName=newValue;}
 });
}
var p1=person("xyz","abc");
console.log(p1.firstName);
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you use `fName` and `lName`? Uhuh, you don't. How do you expect to pass on a value, without passing it on? ;-)

Comment: My idea is to create a firstName property in person object which should have fName value

Comment: could not find a way of how can i do it

Comment: Well, the error is clear. You don't define a `firstName` variable anywhere so `return firstName` throws, and `firstName=newValue` creates a global property in sloppy mode and throws in strict mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `new` up your `Person` to create the Person instance.
As you can see, you can simply use the variables that you passed into the constructor for your getter and setter.
I purposely named the constructor parameters to see how all the variables play together.

In your getter, you return the firstNameFromConstructor variable, or do some processing and then return it.
In your setter, you can change the value of the firstNameFromConstructor variable.

```js
function Person(firstNameFromConstructor, lastNameFromConstructor) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
      get:function() { return firstNameFromConstructor; },
      set:function(newFirstName){  firstNameFromConstructor = newFirstName;}
  });
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
      get:function() { return lastNameFromConstructor; },
      set:function(newLastName){ lastNameFromConstructor = newLastName;}
  });
}

var p1= new Person("xyz","abc");
console.log(p1.firstName);
p1.firstName = 'zyx'
console.log(p1.firstName);
```

Comment: This is based on [this mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Custom_Setters_and_Getters).

Answer (score 2):

In your getter you're returning `firstName`, but it is not defined yet, so right above `Object.defineProperty` declare `firstName` and assign the `fName` argument to it.

Also, when you declare p1 use the `new` operator so your `person` constructor works and assigns `"xyz"` to the `firstName` property.

So, try this:

```js
function person(fName, lName) {

  var firstName = fName;

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {

    get:function() { return firstName; },
    set:function(newValue){firstName=newValue;}

 });

}

var p1 = new person("xyz","abc");

console.log(p1.firstName);

p1.firstName = "abc";

console.log(p1.firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save references to the arguments you pass into the constructor, so that you may get/set them after instantiation.

```
function person(fName, lName) {    
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
    get: function () { return this._firstName; },
    set: function (newValue) { this._firstName = newValue; }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
    get: function () { return this._lastName; },
    set: function (newValue) { this._lastName = newValue; }
  });

  this.firstName = fName;
  this.lastName = lName;
}

var p1 = new person("xyz", "abc");
console.log(p1.firstName);
```

Comment: This only applies for the setter. The getter does not need this if used alone.